# Dump include paths from g++

Tags: path, include, g++, build-automation

I'm trying to write a little build script, and want to determine if the includes are system includes or not. So I want **g++** to tell me the include path's it's using.

`cpp -v` seems the obvious best shot, but it doesn't give me the C++ paths.

So I tried:

```
g++ -Xpreprocessor -v
```

Which doesn't work quite right - **g++** captures the `-v` for it's own verbose output.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

From Jonathan Wakely a better option (works on clang too):

```
g++ -E -x c++ - -v < /dev/null 
clang++ -E -x c++ - -v < /dev/null
```

I noticed there's a flag in cpp for specifying language. This works like a charm.

```
cpp -xc++ -v < /dev/null


#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.7.0/gcc/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.0/4.7.0/../../../../include/c++/4.7.0
 /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.7.0/gcc/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.0/4.7.0/../../../../include/c++/4.7.0/x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.0
 /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.7.0/gcc/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.0/4.7.0/../../../../include/c++/4.7.0/backward
 /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.7.0/gcc/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.0/4.7.0/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.7.0/gcc/include
 /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.7.0/gcc/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.0/4.7.0/include-fixed
 /usr/include
 /System/Library/Frameworks
 /Library/Frameworks
End of search list.
```

Just noticed that it is important for the `-x c++ to be -xc++` on gcc 4.2

Comment: Or equivalently, `g++ -E -x c++ - -v < /dev/null`, which means you can be sure you're using the same `g++` executable as used for compilation

Comment: Cheers - that is a better option. Works on clang too.

Comment: Could simplify that to just `g++ -E -x c++ -v /dev/null`.