# How To Get g++ to list paths to all #included files

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++, include-path

I would like to have g++/gcc tell me the paths to everything non-system it is #include-ing in C++ build.  Turns out, that is a tough search as Google mus-interprets it about ten different ways.

I want these filenames and paths so I can add them to the search path for Exuberant CTAGS.  We have a huge project and if I use ctags on the whole thing it takes about half an hour to generate the tags file and nearly as long for the editor to do a look-up.

We use CMakeLisats to do the compiling.  If there is a directive I can paste into the CMakeLists.txt, that would be extra wonderfulness.

I don't really need the default paths and filenames, Johnathan Wakely gave a good tool for that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11946294/dump-include-paths-from-g).  I think that pretty much covers the fact that this is a cross compile job.  I don't need the cross-system files either.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to invoke g++ with the `-M` option.

From the [manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3.6/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options):

> Instead of outputting the result of preprocessing, output a rule
>   suitable for make describing the dependencies of the main source file.
>   The preprocessor outputs one make rule containing the object file name
>   for that source file, a colon, and the names of all the included
>   files, including those coming from -include or -imacros command line
>   options.

It's worth reading the manual to consider the other `-M` sub options (`-MM` and `-MF` in particular may be of use).

Comment: -MM -MF did the trick.  A note to whomever might use this answer, specifying -MM -MF, or -H blocks actual compilation,  Use it, then comment it out.

Comment: -MM joins short paths on one line. making ambiguous path interpretations. how can you just list them on new lines?

Answer (score 22):

Try `gcc` or `g++` with the `-H` option (to the [preprocessor](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html) part of it). From the [doc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html):

> `-H`
>
> Print the name of each header file used, in addition to other normal activities. Each name is indented to show how deep in the ‘#include’ stack it is. Precompiled header files are also printed, even if they are found to be invalid; an invalid precompiled header file is printed with ‘...x’ and a valid one with ‘...!’ .

It tells you all the headers which are included. You may filter out (with `grep -v` or `awk`) those that you don't want.

You could also consider developing your [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) to register these headers somewhere (e.g. in your [sqlite](https://sqlite.org/) database), perhaps inspired by [this draft](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/bismon-chariot-doc.pdf) report, or the [CHARIOT](http://chariotproject.eu/) or [DECODER](http://decoder-project.eu/) European projects. You could also consider using, or extending, the [Clang static analyzer](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/).

In contrast to the `-M` options suggested in [Oliver Matthews' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20476424/841108), it does not tell you more (but gives all the included files).

Comment: Prettier output than -M, but -MM gets rid of a lot of pesky system files.  In my case, A LOT of pesky files.  I still had to go into the output and remove boost and Qt headers (I used the X2 editor.  grep, sed or awk could also do it).