# Mingw-w64 + codeblocks : No such file or directory

Tags: c++, gcc, windows-8.1, codeblocks, mingw-w64

I have installed *mingw-w64* to have a 64-bits compiler. I used Code Blocks as IDE and i had before a 32 bits *mingw* which is working very well. My OS is windows 8.1.

I have followed this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1nsjGxy1w0U

And the problem I have is this :

> ||=== Build: Release in uvgen (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler (x64)) ===|
>   F:\Document\c++\uvgen\main.cpp|11|fatal error: **GL/glut.h: No such file
>   or directory**| ||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0
>   minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|

I put ( the files `opengl`, `glut` and `glu` from my 32bit-compiler):

`glut32.dll` and `opengl32.dll` in `mingw64/bin`
`GL/glut.h` and others in `mingw64/include` 
and the `libs` in `mingw64/lib`

But my 64bits compiler don't find them :(

Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

The error message indicates that `mingw` cannot find `GL/glut.h`. For you compiler
to find it you either specify an include path `-L PATH_TO/GL/glut.h` on the compile command or
by placing the files in the default include paths.

You can dump the default include paths with `g++ -E -x c++ - -v`
I got that from [Dump include paths from g++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11946294/dump-include-paths-from-g).
If that doesn't help search for how to dump default include paths in `mingw`. You can
always use `-L` option.