# `"apue.h"`is not a global environment PATH , but program can retrieve it

Tags: c

I am learning from [APUE3e](http://www.apuebook.com/apue3e.html)

```
#include "apue.h"
#include <dirent.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    DIR *dp;
    struct dirent *dirp;
  ....
```

In the header, import a user-definded module `"apue.h"`. the program run correctly after compiled.

The `apue.h` is placed in `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include`,

What confuse me is that `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include` is not in the $PATH but could be retrieved by the program globally.

```
$ echo $PATH | grep include
#does not return anything.
```

How could the program get it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$PATH` is where the shell looks for *executables*, not header files. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11946294/dump-include-paths-from-g) shows how you can get the compiler to show you where it's looking for header files.