# Can't compile with mingw-w64 g++: can't find <wchar.h>

Tags: c++, mingw-w64

I have the simple C++ program

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile using `g++ test.cpp` I get this error

```
In file included from C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/postypes.h:40,
                 from C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/iosfwd:40,
                 from C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/ios:38,
                 from C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/ostream:38,
                 from C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/iostream:39,
                 from test.cpp:1:
C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/cwchar:44:10: fatal error: wchar.h: No such file or directory
 #include <wchar.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

output for `g++ -v`:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../../../src/gcc-8.1.0/configure --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --prefix=/mingw64 --with-sysroot=/c/mingw810/x86_64-810-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64 --enable-shared --enable-static --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-threads=posix --enable-libgomp --enable-libatomic --enable-lto --enable-graphite --enable-checking=release --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-bootstrap --disable-rpath --disable-win32-registry --disable-nls --disable-werror --disable-symvers --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --with-arch=nocona --with-tune=core2 --with-libiconv --with-system-zlib --with-gmp=/c/mingw810/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-mpfr=/c/mingw810/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-mpc=/c/mingw810/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-isl=/c/mingw810/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-pkgversion='x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project' --with-bugurl=https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64 CFLAGS='-O2 -pipe -fno-ident -I/c/mingw810/x86_64-810-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/opt/include -I/c/mingw810/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/include -I/c/mingw810/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/include' CXXFLAGS='-O2 -pipe -fno-ident -I/c/mingw810/x86_64-810-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/opt/include -I/c/mingw810/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/include -I/c/mingw810/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/include' CPPFLAGS=' -I/c/mingw810/x86_64-810-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/opt/include -I/c/mingw810/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/include -I/c/mingw810/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/include' LDFLAGS='-pipe -fno-ident -L/c/mingw810/x86_64-810-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/opt/lib -L/c/mingw810/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/lib -L/c/mingw810/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/lib '
Thread model: posix
gcc version 8.1.0 (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project)
```

I'm on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to find this file in the MinGw directory `C:\mingw-w64\`?

If it exists then check if its path is in [g++ include paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11946294/dump-include-paths-from-g).

If not add it to your building command.